# Errors when creating Realm object classes

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to write a simple app in Swift, backed with Realm. When I write `var`s within classes, I keep getting errors such as "`Property cannot be implicitly @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`". Sometimes these errors (which seem to involve Objective-C, which I'm not using) appear and sometimes they don't--See screenshots below.

I'm an admitted Newbie to Swift, but I thought I understood enough to get started. Specifically:

1) Should I add "`@objc`" before the class declaration?

2) Should I add "`@objc`" before the dynamic var declaration?

3) It seems that a `Float` var must be initialized, but not so for `String`?

4) Why does the compiler complain about a declaration on one line, but not about identical syntax in the next line?

Would sure appreciate some guidance, or pointers to specific instructions for creating Realm object classes!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon the error comes from calling `@objc` instead of `@objcMembers`.
Try change

```
@objc class Transaction: Object
```

to

```
@objcMembers class Transaction: Object
```

And remove all `@objc` in front of your dynamic variables. So your final code should look like:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers class Transaction: Object {
    dynamic var picPath: String?
    dynamic var transAmount: Float = 0.0
}

@objcMembers class Transaction: Object {
    dynamic var currentBalance: Float = 0.0
    dynamic var highWaterBalance: Float = 0.0
    dynamic var acctName: String?
}
```

Our fellow [Paul Hudson has described this attribute on his site hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objcmembers-attribute).